# Reference request: existence/uniqueness of solutions to convection diffusion equations

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, existence-theorems, uniqueness-theorems

I am looking for a reference wherein existence and uniqueness results are proven for a system of PDEs of the form
$$
 \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} + A \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = f(Q,x,t) + \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x^2}
$$
where $Q:(x,t) \mapsto \mathbb{R}^N$ and $A:(Q,x,t) \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ has a complete set of distinct real eigenvalues, that is a system of convection-diffusion style parabolic PDEs. I will be applying to a system in the flux form,
$$
 \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (F(Q,x,t)) = g(Q,x,t) + \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x^2}
$$
for $F:(Q,x,t) \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{N}$, so that form is also good. The Cauchy problem with $Q$ specified at $t=0$ on $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is best, or a class of boundary value problems if that's easier to find. Thanks!

**Edit**

I have found a book detailing the boundary value problem with homogeneous Dirishlet conditions, specificly `linear and quasi-Linear equations of the parabolic type' by Ladyzenskaja, Solonnikov and Uralceva. I am still interested in the Cauchy problem if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: There are many textbooks covering parabolic PDEs. Unless you are looking for something specific that in not covered in textbooks, this question is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: @Michael Renardy I've looked in Evans, Friedman and Garabedian, none of them discuss the type of system specified above. Looking through papers published in the last 10 years or so they all concern themselves with more sofisticated systems, so I assume this system has been delt with. If you know many textbooks that give existance and uniquness of the equations given, or reference where this was prooved, then perhaps you could list a few? Even one?

Comment: @MIchael Renardy To clarify, normally I would brouse books in the library to try and find somthing, but due to covid I have to request textbooks, and wait a week before I get access to them. This prevents me from flicking through promising textbooks, and finding ones with a promising contents/index item. It would be very helpful if I could know, a week in advance of getting a book, whether it has the information I need.